# Drag and Drop not working in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, drag-and-drop

The code is working in my `Activity`, but not in my `Fragment`. I can see the elements there, but I can't drag and drop them, it stops in long click.

Can someone provide a solution?

**Error log:**

```
*E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                   
Process: com.example.future.buildingautomationsystem, PID: 10526 
         java.lang.NullPointerException
         at com.example.future.buildingautomationsystem.slidefragment.onItemLongClick(slidefragment.java:179)
         at android.widget.AbsListView.performLongPress(AbsListView.java:3175)
         at android.widget.AbsListView$CheckForLongPress.run(AbsListView.java:3124)
         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5395)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:837)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:653)
         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)*
```

**Code:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.ClipDescription;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.DragEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnDragListener;
import android.view.View.OnLongClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class slidefragment extends Fragment implements OnDragListener,
        OnItemLongClickListener {

    ArrayList drawables;

    private BaseAdapter adapter;
    private int draggedIndex = -1;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View v;
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slidefragment, container,false);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        drawables = new ArrayList();
        drawables.add(R.drawable.ico1);
        drawables.add(R.drawable.ico1);
        drawables.add(R.drawable.ico1);
        drawables.add(R.drawable.ico1);
        drawables.add(R.drawable.ico1);
        drawables.add(R.drawable.ico1);
        drawables.add(R.drawable.ico1);
        drawables.add(R.drawable.ico1);
        drawables.add(R.drawable.ico1);
        GridView gridView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
        gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(slidefragment.this);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter = new BaseAdapter() {

            @Override
            // Get a View that displays the data at the specified position in
            // the data set.
            public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                                ViewGroup gridView) {
                // try to reuse the views.
                ImageView view = (ImageView) convertView;
                // if convert view is null then create a new instance else reuse
                // it
                if (view == null) {
                    view = new ImageView(getActivity().getBaseContext());
                }
                view.setImageResource((Integer) drawables.get(position));
                view.setTag(String.valueOf(position));
                return view;
            }

            @Override
            // Get the row id associated with the specified position in the
            // list.
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            @Override
            // Get the data item associated with the specified position in the
            // data set.
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return drawables.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            // How many items are in the data set represented by this Adapter.
            public int getCount() {
                return drawables.size();
            }
        });
        return v;
    }

   // @Override
  //  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     // getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_login,getView().menu);
     //   return true;
    //}

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(final View view, DragEvent dragEvent) {
        switch (dragEvent.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                // Drag has started
                // If called for trash resize the view and return true
                if (view.getId() == R.id.droplayout) {
                    view.animate().scaleX(1.0f);
                    view.animate().scaleY(1.0f);
                    return true;
                } else // else check the mime type and set the view visibility
                    if (dragEvent.getClipDescription().hasMimeType(
                            ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)) {
                        view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        return true;

                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                // Drag has entered view bounds
                // If called for trash can then scale it.
                if (view.getId() == R.id.droplayout) {
                    view.animate().scaleX(1.5f);
                    view.animate().scaleY(1.5f);
                }
                return true;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                // Drag exited view bounds
                // If called for trash can then reset it.
                if (view.getId() == R.id.droplayout) {
                    view.animate().scaleX(1.0f);
                    view.animate().scaleY(1.0f);
                }
                view.invalidate();
                return true;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
                // Ignore this event
                return true;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                // Dropped inside view bounds
                // If called for trash can then delete the item and reload the grid
                // view
                if (view.getId() == R.id.droplayout) {
                    drawables.remove(draggedIndex);
                    draggedIndex = -1;
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                // Hide the trash can
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                       view. findViewById(R.id.droplayout).setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    }
                }, 1000l);
                if (view.getId() == R.id.droplayout) {
                    view.animate().scaleX(1.0f);
                    view.animate().scaleY(1.0f);
                } else {
                    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                // remove drag listeners
                view.setOnDragListener(null);
                return true;

        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView gridView, View view,
                                   int position, long row) {
        ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((String) view.getTag());
        ClipData clipData = new ClipData((CharSequence) view.getTag(),
                new String[] { ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN }, item);
        view.startDrag(clipData, new View.DragShadowBuilder(view), null, 0);
        View trashCan = view.findViewById(R.id.linearlayoutbottom);
        trashCan.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        trashCan.setOnDragListener(slidefragment.this);

        trashCan.setOnDragListener(slidefragment.this);
        draggedIndex = position;
        return true;
    }

    public LayoutInflater getMenuInflater() {
        return getMenuInflater();
    }
}
```

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException on .slidefragment.onItemLongClick - make sure it's not null obviously

Comment: Ok that exception is handled, but cases of onDrag not working.No error is showing.. I had given a Toast on ACTION_DRAG_ENDED that not showing in fragment but when i try the same on activity its working.

Comment: hmm, in the runnable for ACTION_DRAG_ENDED, you change a view. You're in the runnable/handler (which is a different thread)- normally you get an exception for that, look into runOnUiThread, you can only touch views on the ui thread

Comment: But It is working on Activity... Is there need a change in fragment?  I am new in android thats why am asking.

Comment: can you post the stack trace for this particular issue? It's very hard to speculate about code issues when people aren't sure themselves, chum! Also, a common thing to do is to create a Toast.makeText and not call show() on it - make sure you're doing that if you want to see your toast. But manipulating views from non-ui threads throw exceptions. Fragment is a slightly different scenario, but same stuff still applies